# Is Sunan an-Nasa'i 5400 Daif or authentic?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

solely looking at sunnah.com(https://sunnah.com/nasai:5400) it tells us that the hadith is weak based on the rating of Darussalam

But looking at the main book it also mentions that it was rated as Dai'f but also considered as authentic by *shaykh al Albani* and *Muhammad bin Ali Al wallawi* on page 209 of the PDF file(https://ia903400.us.archive.org/25/items/islamic-english-books-collection/Sunan_an-Nasa%27i%2C_Volume_6.pdf)

Comment: The obvious answer to this is that there is disagreement among the scholars on the grade of the hadith.